# T-sql multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestFactSales]
( [SalesOrderID]
, [SalesOrderDetailID]
, [OrderDateKey] -- Surrogate Key
, [ShipDateKey] -- Surrogate Key
, [CustomerKey] -- Surrogate Key
, [ProductKey] -- Surrogate Key
, [OrderQty]
, [UnitPrice]
, [UnitPriceDiscount]
) 
SELECT 
  T2.SalesOrderID
, T1.SalesOrderDetailID
--, T2.OrderDate
, T6.CalendarDateKey
--, T2.ShipDate
, T5.CalendarDateKey
--, T2.CustomerID
, T4.CustomerKey
--, T1.ProductID
, T3.ProductKey
, T1.OrderQty
, T1.UnitPrice
, T1.UnitPriceDiscount
FROM  [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as T1

JOIN [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as T2
  ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID

JOIN Tempdb.dbo.TestDimProducts as T3
 ON T1.ProductID = T3.ProductID

JOIN TempDB.dbo.TestDimCustomers as T4
 ON T2.CustomerID = T4.CustomerID

JOIN TempDB.dbo.TestDimDates as T5
 ON Cast(T2.ShipDate as date) = Cast(T5.CalendarDate as date)

JOIN TempDB.dbo.TestDimDates as T6
 ON Cast(T2.OrderDate as date) = Cast(T6.CalendarDate as date)

;
go
```

Hello,
I have a problem about understating the code above. This is t-sql statement for very common join operations in data warehouse implementation. My problem is that when we join two tables with:

```
FROM  [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as T1
JOIN [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as T2
 ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID
```

Does it mean that join tables T1 and T2 on T2 ? As in select statement, we have

```
Select
T2.SalesOrderID
, T1.SalesOrderDetailID
```

Hence how this select understands which table to look at,T1 or T2?
Can you please clarify me about this issue? Please note that I understand the alias representation. What I dont understand is insert part. To insert [SalesOrderID], we need to take a look at joined table coming from T1 and T2. but the code looks T2.SalesOrderID.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: Hi Ben why do you think so? This is about general understanding about multiple joins and data warehouse fact table creation, hence can be helpful for starters

Comment: there are already many questions of that type, so in that case it would be a duplicate. Either way it should be closed.

Comment: for sure, i searched for similar questions, but could not find any related answer. Instead of commenting " unlikely to help anyone else", you should have been more constructive by providing link to answers that you think would be helpful. Moreover, there are some answers to the question, people put some effort and time. It is also  not respectful to them.

Comment: Are you asking how the insert works? The Insert is specifying columns and the select is the value. So the `SalesOrderID` in the insert is the column on that table, not any value. The **value** is coming from t2.SalesOrderId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A joined table is the combination of all the columns from both tables - it doesn't make a new table, it just samples from both. For example:

- Table1 is made up of 2 columns, ID and name
- Table2 is made up of 2 columns, ID and description
- Joining them together now gives 4 columns to work from, Table1.ID, Table1.name, Table2.ID, Table2.description
- Every row in Table1 could appear in the join next to every row from Table2
- The joined table is filtered to show only rows specified in the `ON` clause - so in your case, rows where T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID

You have used the statement `insert into (columns) select ... from joined table`.

- Your table has all the columns from both T1 and T2 available to use.
- In the select part of this statement, you specify which columns you want to use when you insert into `TestFactSales`.
- Both tables have a column named `SalesOrderID`, so if you just put that, SQL doesn't know which table to take that column from.
- Remember that this joined table has all the columns from both T1 and T2, so it contains the columns T1.SalesOrderID and T2.SalesOrderID
- In your join, you specified that T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID in the `ON` clause. This means they are the same for everything in your joined table.
- In this particular case then, it doesn't matter to you whether the SalesOrderID comes from T1 or T2 as they are the same by definition.

HOWEVER:

- That is not always the case, and SQL Server has no way of knowing.
- Sometimes tables will have the same column name, but are joined on something different.
- So just asking for T1.mycolumn could give a different answer to T2.mycolumn.
- This is why you need to specifiy which of the original tables the column comes from.

Comment: That is the explanation that I was looking for. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that join tables T1 and T2 on T2 ?

It's joining the tables `SalesOrderDetail` and `SalesOrderHeader`, and aliasing them as `T1` and `T2` respectively.

> Hence how this select understands which table to look at,T1 or T2?

It's explicitly specified in the query:

```
SELECT 
  T2.SalesOrderID
, T1.SalesOrderDetailID
```

So the query is looking for `SalesOrderID` in the table `T2` (which is an alias for `SalesOrderHeader`), and looking for `SalesOrderDetailID` in the table `T1` (which is an alias for `SalesOrderDetail`).

---

This (with table aliases):

```
SELECT 
  T2.SalesOrderID,
  T1.SalesOrderDetailID
FROM SalesOrderDetail AS T1
  JOIN SalesOrderHeader AS T2
  ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID
```

Would be the same as this (without table aliases):

```
SELECT
  SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID,
  SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderDetailID
FROM SalesOrderDetail
  JOIN SalesOrderHeader
  ON SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
```

Using a table alias in a query simply shortens all of the duplication of long tables names throughout the query.  (Though the use of aliases such as `T1` and `T2` seems to obscure useful information about those tables, but perhaps this code was auto-generated by a tool which wouldn't have the ability to use meaningful alias names.)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer. Question is also related to insert statement. The script also inserts [SalesOrderID] with T2.SalesOrderID . However, shoudnt we insert it with joined table coming from : FROM  [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as T1

JOIN [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as T2
  ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID   istead of T2. T2 is just SalesOrderHeader not joined table.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is using `T1` and `T2` as an alias. The `AS` clause creates a table alias. So `[AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail` is can now be referenced as`T1`.

```
 FROM  [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as T1 JOIN
 [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as T2  ON
 T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID
```

In the select statement `T1` is equivalent to `[AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail` when you type `ALIAS.Column_Name` sql will is smart enough to look up what the alias is and search the correct table

```
 Select
 T2.SalesOrderID
 , T1.SalesOrderDetailID
```

[MSDN on Table aliasing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer. Question is also related to insert statement. The script also inserts [SalesOrderID] with T2.SalesOrderID . However, shoudnt we insert it with joined table coming from : FROM [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as T1 JOIN [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as T2 ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID istead of T2. T2 is just SalesOrderHeader not joined table.

Answer (score 0):

The query is looking at both tables `[AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail` and `[AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader`.  This is a one-to-many relationship.

The `T1` and `T2` is just an alias for the long table names.

`SalesOrderHeader` contains general info such as SalesOrderId, customerId, orderDate.

The `SalesOrderDetail` table contains item(s) ordered for this particular `SalesOrderId`.  The table contains at least SalesOrderId, ItemId, Quantity.

Joining these 2 tables will give information about what items are purchased by customer on this particular invoice.  The join condition will be `T2.SalesOrderId = T1.SalesOrderId`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer. Question is also related to insert statement. The script also inserts [SalesOrderID] with T2.SalesOrderID . However, shoudnt we insert it with joined table coming from : FROM [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as T1 JOIN [AdventureWorksLT2012].SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as T2 ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID istead of T2. T2 is just SalesOrderHeader not joined table.

Comment: `ON T1.SalesOrderID = T2.SalesOrderID` is a join condition.  Since this is an equality join, it doesn't matter which one is used.